# ¿Como eliminar el efecto de subrayado que sucede al pasar por encima el puntero del ratón?

Tags: css, css3

Tengo un problema con los iconos a redes sociales. Cuando les pasas por encima el ratón, además de cambiar de color, aparece una línea negra en los propios iconos (Creo que es un subrayado).

Me gustaría resolverlo a través del CSS.

Los códigos de los botones son:

Es Wordpress, el tema es Twenty Seventeen y el pluguin que estoy usando es Social Icons Widget by WPZOOM.

En :Hover aplica box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), 0 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);...

Comment: Por favor revisa [ask]  y [mcve] para que te podamos ayudar mejor.

Comment: Buenas, pathsoldier. Has de mostrar el codigo html de los iconos y el css que se aplica a cada uno. Lee el [tour] y [ask] para aprender como funciona el sitio y como hacer preguntas de calidad. Un saludo

Comment: @David En los comentarios los enlaces funcionan poniendo el texto entre `[]` y todo seguido, sin espacios, entre `()` el link. O sea: `[texto](link)`.  [Cómo quitar subrayado del enlace](https://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwicpNGtnMLUAhXFLlAKHcjbBGIQFggmMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fes.ccm.net%2Ffaq%2F9250-quitar-el-subrayado-de-los-enlaces-en-html-css&usg=AFQjCNFSsi66zVthM5rOzPYuisfLvMAH-w)

Comment: Gracias @A.Cedano :)

Comment: @pathsoldier, por favor aclara en la pregunta que estás usando wordpress, con el tema *twentyseventeen*, y que en `:hover` aplica `box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), 0 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);`... deberías generar un [mcve] en tu pregunta.

Comment: Gracias por vuestros comentarios.

Answer (score 1):

¿Has probado con `text-decoration: none` en este grupo de tu css:?

```
.zoom-social_icons-list__item a:hover .socicon,
.zoom-social_icons-list__item a:hover .dashicons,
.zoom-social_icons-list__item a:hover .genericon,
.zoom-social_icons-list__item a:hover .fa
{
    opacity: 0.8;
    text-decoration: none;   
}
```

Comment: Perdonar, soy nuevo en esto. Gracias por las aclaraciones. Desgraciadamente el código que me has dado no soluciona el error Juan Manuel.

Los códigos de los botones son:

<span class="socicon socicon-twitter" style="; font-size: 30px; padding:8px"></span>

<span class="socicon socicon-linkedin" style="background-color:rgb(59, 89, 152); font-size: 30px; padding:8px"></span>

Es Wordpress, el tema es Twenty Seventeen y el pluguin que estoy usando es Social Icons Widget by WPZOOM.

En :Hover aplica box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), 0 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);...

Comment: @pathsoldier me he instalado de prueba WordPress, con el tema Twenty Seventeen, y el plugin Social Icons Widget. Veo lo que me dices y he probado con diferentes clases de css. Lo más parecido a lo que hace el tema, es cambiar la clase [zoom-social_icons-list__link] que está en el archivo [class.zoom-social-icons-widget.php] en la línea 1369, y le he puesto [site-title]. Mira el efecto que hace y dime si te gusta así.

Comment: Solucionado, he optado por comprar una plantilla de pago. Me estaba rompiendo demasiado la cabeza! Gracias por vuestra ayuda a todos. Agradezco mucho que me hayáis dedicado un tiempo.